# How to Retrieve the Traffic Flow Information of a Precise Location/RW/Coordinate

Tags: here-api

Given a coordinate/RW/location, I'm trying to retrieve traffic flow information about that location in which I'm mostly interested in JF (Jam Factor) and FF (Free Flow Speed)

The thing is that I'm making a query with *prox* option. I'm supplying a quite small radius e.g., 0.0001 meters. However, the XML file I get in turn, has a lot of RW items, even the ones that are quite far from the coordinate I've supplied.

> ```
> https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.2/flow.xml/?app_id={my_app_id}&app_code={my_app_code}&prox=lat,long,0.0001
> ```

Is there a way to retrieve only the RW that is closest to the coordinates I've sent?

Comment: Please provide the lat,lng for which you are facing the issue.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport 40.972884,29.253977,0.0001

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are having the same issue and didn't yet find a workaround. I found another API that is capable of sending more reasonable flow information.

[TomTom Flow API](https://developer.tomtom.com/traffic-api/traffic-api-documentation-traffic-flow/flow-segment-data)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum and default radius in prox parameter is 250m. So even if you provide 0.0001 you will get data for minimum of 250m.